# adding headers to csv from sqlite3 using php

Tags: php

I am newbie.I am trying to add headers to csv extracted data from sqlite3 database  but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$db = new sqlite3('I:\webbs.db');

$results = $db->query('select Id   ,CompanyId  ,DateTime  ,Serial  ,DeviceId  ,AgentAId  ,GpsAddress  ,Targa  ,CommonRoadDescription  ,RoadCivicNumber  ,VehicleBrandDescription  

,VehicleModelDescription  ,VerbaliVehicleTypeDescription  ,CommonColorVehicleDescription  ,VerbaliRuleOneCode  ,VerbaliRuleOneDescription  ,VerbaliRuleOnePoints  ,VerbaliClosedNoteDescription  

,Points  ,VerbaliMissedNotificationDescription  ,MissedNotificationNote  ,StatementNote  from VerbaliData');


$fp = fopen('explorer.csv', 'w');



while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_BOTH)) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: Well where are the `headers` on your code ?

Comment: Hi  Shankar, the query ... the sql select statment are the headers right.can you help me please.. I am not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not doing something like this?:

```
$headers = array('CompanyId', 'DateTime', 'Serial', ...);
results = $db->query('SELECT ' . implode(',', $headers) . ' FROM table');

$fp = fopen('explorer.csv', 'w');

// write headers
fputcsv($fp, $headers);

// write data. I would use SQLITE3_NUM. This makes more sense
while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_NUM)) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Hi hek I tried your code i am gettting this error at the end. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\.....\downnload.php on line 13`

Comment: sorry, this was a typo